# Eclipse 3.x key bindings are removed when migrated to e4 (Eclipse Luna ) series

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, keyboard-shortcuts, e4, xmi

The key bindings that I defined in my 3.x RCP workspace :

```
   <extension
   id="vebscheme.scheme"
   name="vebscheme.scheme"
   point="org.eclipse.ui.bindings">

    <key
       commandId="com.ami.veb.ui.menu.file.new.command"
       contextId="com.ami.veb.ui.context"
       schemeId="com.ami.veb.ui.scheme"
       sequence="CTRL+N"/>  
    <key
      commandId="com.ami.veb.ui.menu.file.openexternalfile.command"
      contextId="com.ami.veb.ui.context"
      schemeId="com.ami.veb.ui.scheme"
      sequence="CTRL+O"/>
    <key     
      commandId="com.ami.veb.ui.menu.file.new.components.addcomponentwizard.command"
      contextId="com.ami.veb.ui.context"
      schemeId="com.ami.veb.ui.scheme"
      sequence="CTRL+ALT+A"/>   
    <key
         commandId="com.ami.veb.ui.menu.file.new.components.updatecomponentwizard.command"  
      contextId="com.ami.veb.ui.context"
      schemeId="com.ami.veb.ui.scheme"
      sequence="CTRL+ALT+U"/>

      /** Scheme for the key-bindings **/
       <scheme
      id="com.ami.veb.ui.scheme"
      name="com.ami.veb.ui.scheme">
       </scheme>

      //----------------
       -----------------//
  </extension>
```

Scheme Activation :

```
    IBindingService bindingService = (IBindingService)PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getAdapter(IBindingService.class);
    BindingService bindingServiceObj = (BindingService) bindingService;
    //get the binding manager for the binding service
    BindingManager bindingManager = bindingServiceObj.getBindingManager();

    //constructs a scheme instance with the schemeId
    Scheme newScheme = bindingManager.getScheme("com.ami.veb.ui.scheme");
    //check if the newScheme is not null
    //then set the scheme as active scheme
    if(newScheme != null) {
        try {
            bindingManager.setActiveScheme(newScheme);
        } catch (NotDefinedException e) {
            String message = "Problem occurred when updating current active scheme."+
                    " This may result in issues with shortcut key bindings. "+
                    "Exit and re-launch the application to resolve this issue";
            VeBLogger.getInstance().log(message);
            VeBPluginActivator.getDefault().logPluginError(e);
        }
    }
```

Context Activation :

```
     IContextService contextService = (IContextService) PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getService(IContextService.class);
    contextService.activateContext("com.ami.veb.ui.context");
```

I've generated a product (with Luna). I observed that the keyboard shortcuts are not working as soon as I launch the product (until I do a save on the shortcuts).

```
BindingTable table = getTable(c.getId());
        if (table != null) {
            currentResult = table.getPerfectMatch(triggerSequence);
        }
```

While debugging, I noticed that the `BindingTable table` is empty initially for my binding context, and therefore I'm getting Eclipse defined shortcuts and not the one which I'd defined for my context.

P.S. I recently migrated my RCP workspace from Eclipse Indigo (3.x RCP) to Luna (e4 series) and I observed that as soon as I export my RCP product my bindings got cleared and when I try to press any short-cut key (say Ctrl+N) I am able to see only the eclipse shortcuts and not the one which I'd defined in my plugin.xml.

Also, Please note that the migration is a partial migration (or soft migration) and not a complete migration (pure 'e4') and the application is still based on the compatibility layer.

The key bindings (defined in plugin.xml) pertained to the my binding context are getting cleared upon product launch.

I'm confused on what went wrong with the migration :( :(

Suggestions are welcomed and will be appreciated !

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by '3.x code to build on Eclipse e4'. You either stick with all 3.x compatibility code but use Eclipse 4 in which case everything should still work, or you switch to the e4 model which requires a lot of work converting all of the 3.x code to e4. If you are using e4 you should use the latest Eclipse Mars.

Comment: @greg-449: By '3.x code to build on Eclipse e4', I mean that I removed the deprecated methods from 3.x and and I replaced with e4 counterparts, so that the resulting workspace builds without any compilation errors.  With this, If I export my product (with Luna) the shortcuts are not working.

Comment: Is my description is clear ?  Please correct me, If my presentation is wrong.

Comment: If this is `org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings.internal.BindingTable` that is an **internal** class and you should not be using it. `IBindingService` is the official API.

Comment: I'm not using it, I just tried to debug the **internal** class (BindingTable) for gaining a deep insight to the problem.

Comment: Can you please suggest a solution for the issue, Anything I'm missing.
why the shortcuts are not working as soon as I launch my product.

Comment: @greg-449: I had updated my question to express my problem still better.
Could you please help me at this point.   Any sort of hint will help me in fixing this bug.

Comment: I still don't understand what you mean by 'partial migration'. A 3.x application should just run under Eclipse 4 without any changes.

Comment: @greg-449: But, I coudn't able to execute the short cuts keys with my 3.x code imported on top of Luna.  The short-cuts are working only if I save my bindings into the preferences, and it is not working as soon as I launch the RCP product.

Comment: Show us the `org.eclipse.ui.bindings` definitions (or whatever it is you are using the define the keys)

Comment: @greg-449 : I had updated the question to contain the extension points which I had defined in my 3.x RCP workspace.

Comment: The keys are in a Scheme, so how are you defining the Scheme? How are you activating it? The keys also have a context id, how are you activating the context?

Comment: @greg-449 : The scheme is defined in the plugin.xml itslef. I had updated the question to contain the `<schemes>` also.                                               The context `com.ami.veb.ui.context` and the scheme `com.ami.veb.ui.scheme` are being activated at the perspectiveActivated(IWorkbenchPage, IPerspectiveDescriptor) method   of the class that implements the IPerspectiveListener3 and IWorkbenchListener.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104632/discussion-between-ragu-and-greg-449).

Comment: @greg-449 : Any idea on what could be the problem ? I have updated my question to contain code snippets for `scheme` and `context` activation. Both activation takes place in perspectiveActivated() method.

Comment: Your code to set the scheme uses the **internal** class `BindingService`. I guess that this has been changed so that this code no longer works. There does not appear to be an official API to set the scheme and I don't know how you would do that.

Comment: @greg-449 : So, defining scheme could be the problem with e4 ?
 If I remove the scheme id  from `plugin.xml` and from the `activation code` then the bindings will work ?

Comment: This code works fine with 3.x Eclipse series, and I'm wondering how the same code works fine in debug mode and not in exported RCP (of Eclipse Luna) ?    In debug mode if I launch the product, then I am able to execute the short-cuts.  The shortcuts fails only if in the exported RCP product

Comment: @greg-449 : Any workaround exists  for resolving the issue ?   If I move my bindings from plugin.xml to application.xmi file, will it work ?

Comment: Can you please help me to resolve the issue, any work-around will be appreciated. Thanks !!

Comment: Sorry but I have no further suggestions.

Comment: @greg-449 : I found the solution for this issue, actually `org.eclipse.ui.bindings.BindingManager` is no longer valid for e4 architecutre and so I believe the following code has no effect (in e4) : `bindingManager.setActiveScheme(newScheme);` . To fix this what I did is I used the `BindingTableManager` of the `org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings` plugin and `BindingTableManager.setActiveSchemes(String[])` works well.

Comment: I retreived the instance to the `BindingTableManager` using Dependency Injection `@Inject
 private BindingTableManager manager;`   Please provide your feedback as to how it is working now... I dont know what Im doing, just Im trying some alternatives... Please provide your inputs